# My MIPS program thinks every user input is the number 4

Tags: assembly, input, integer, output, mips

This assembly code was created to multiply two numbers together.
I've been programming .s programs and executing them in QTSpim for all of 3 days now, though I've been learning about how to do so for over 2 months.  I learned that you can take an integer as user input and store it to a temporary register for use; however, when I attempted this simple task I found that my user input would always become the same number: 4.  The code will be shown below.

NOTES WHEN LOOKING FOR THE PROBLEM:

- I wouldn't worry about the part of the program that prevents negative inputs when searching for the problem in this code, but I've left it in just in case that is where the problem arises from.
- Just from what I've learned from trying to fix this program I think there might be a problem with how I define and utilize arg1 and arg2.  If you're looking for them, they're created near the top of the code and are integral in retrieving, storing, and loading the user's input into the temporary registers ($t2 and $t3) in nearly every step of the code.
- The answer is always stored in $t1 and $t1 always starts as 0.  After doing a line by line evaluation of the code, I can conclude that there's nothing wrong with the register $t1 so I wouldn't bother looking at that.
- Anything following a pound symbol (#) will be my thought process at every step of the code.  This could be very useful in figuring out where I went wrong.
- The indentation looks a bit different on Stack Overflow, but if you think that the problem could arise from indentation, please feel free to point that out, I have no clue if improper indentation could lead to errors

Code:

```
.data   

request_input:
.asciiz "Please enter the numbers you would like to multiply: \n"
give_output:
.asciiz "The numbers multiply to give: "
neg_input:
.asciiz "Sorry, this program doesn't work with negative inputs. \n"
arg1: .word 4
arg2: .word 4

.text
.globl main

main:
#Output the request for user input
la  $a0, request_input
li  $v0, 4
syscall

#Takes the user's input and stores it to temp registers
la  $a0, arg1
la  $a1, arg1
li  $v0, 5 #op code for getting an integer input
syscall
lw  $t2, arg1 #store the input to temp register 2

la  $a0, arg2
la  $a1, arg2
li  $v0, 5 #op code for getting an integer input
syscall
lw  $t3, arg2 #store the input to temp register 3

#sets t1 to zero so we can reliably store the answer into it
addi    $t1, $zero, 0

#checks if the arguments are less than zero, if so goes to output zero
blez    $t2, negzero
blez    $t3, negzero
bgtz    $t3, fori

negzero:
#what happens if an argument is negative
la  $a0, neg_input
li  $v0, 4
syscall

la  $a0, 0($t1)
li  $v0, 1
syscall

li  $v0, 10
syscall

fori:
#Does the math
add $t1, $t1, $t2
addi    $t3, $t3, -1
bnez    $t3, fori

fin:
#Outputs the answer
la  $a0, give_output
li  $v0, 4
syscall

la  $a0, 0($t1)
li  $v0, 1
syscall

li  $v0, 10
syscall}
```

Comment: The `read integer` syscall returns the integer in `$v0`, and it takes no arguments. Pay more attention to the documentation. You need something like: `li $v0, 5; syscall; move $t2, $v0` to read an integer into `$t2`.